# How to extract rows from dataframe by factors?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe, and now I would like to extract some rows by a column content. For example:

```
name <- c("John","Lily","Cat","King")
record <- c(2,6,10,3)
dftry <- data.frame(name,record)
list <- c("John","cat")
```

I want to extract the row which dftry$name == "John" | "cat" (which is in the list) how can I do that? I have tried

```
dftry[dftry$name==list,]  #but this do not gonna work
dftry[which(dftry$name == "John"| dftry$name =="Cat"),]  #this would work but the real list is thousands long than 2.
```

So how can I do it easily? Thank you

Comment: Try `dftry[dftry$name %in% list,]`.

Comment: You can try `subset(dftry, name %in% list)`.

Comment: @jay.sf you are the day saver. Could u tell me what is this %in%  and convert this to an answer？

Comment: @Codezy If you're not sure what something in R is, first try the help file, in this case by running `help("%in%")`

Comment: @Codezy It's actually `match()` type `?"%in%"`.

Comment: @duckmayr learned it thank you

Comment: @jay.sf yeah thank you I also figured it out